# Is there a portable and clean way to set the __proto__ property of functions?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I know IE doesn't support `__proto__`, but I'm thinking about functions. `new Constructor` can only set the hidden `__proto__` of the automatically created objects, if a function is returned it's `__proto__` is untouched, and ES5's `Oject.create` can't create a function. How can I set the `__proto__` of a function? You may suggest to set properties on `Function.prototype`, but that's not a clean approach. I also want to avoid directly setting properties on individual functions, because it's neither clean nor memory friendly, after all a new property, even only a reference, could consume at least 4 bytes on 32 platform, whereas `__proto__` is mandatory hence worths nothing. Please bear with my stinginess ;) So, does anyone know how to do this without resorting to `__proto__`? Thanks in advance!

--->8---

Edit:

My intention is to use `arguments.callee`s as normal objects, which have methods of their own, and I think it would be groovy if I could put those methods in a prototype.

Comment: So you want a `someFunction`->`myCustomObject`->`Function.prototype`->`Object.prototype`->`null` prototype chain?

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated, you should name your functions instead. But yes, it makes no difference if you want to access the inherited props of functions from in- or outside